# HTML tag <object> does not work after being moved in DOM using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, flash

In the following example the flash in my HTML would not show after moving it's parent element in DOM. I use `appendChild` on enclosing `div` of my `object` element to move it somewhere else in the DOM hierarchy, but after the move is complete the containing flash would not show.

I get this error in `IE 10` and `firefox`, in `Chrome` there seems to be no problem.

This error happened in much larger project, but I managed to distill it to the following little example.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
     var copy = document.getElementById("s");
     document.getElementById("newparent").appendChild(copy); //if I comment out this line, example works
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="newparent"> <!-- here will the object be appended -->
  </div>
  <div id="s">
    <object width="50%" height="50%" data="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf">SWF Not shown</object>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I comment out the second line of my `onload` function, the flash shows properly (but it is not moved around). I am not able to google anything. Perhaps I am not able to describe my problem, I am pretty new to HTML. Thanks in advice.

Comment: The real question is; why are you using Flash in this day and age?

Comment: @adeneo school thing =(

Comment: No, the real question is why you can't initialize object already in `newparent`.

Comment: Some jQuery does the trick -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B34nv/), so that means it's possible in plain jS aswell.

Comment: @adeneo does it? I get the `SWF Not shown` in the fiddle you posted. (using firefox or IE 10, chrome works)

Comment: I only checked it with Chrome, and if it does'nt work with FF, I guess moving swf is not allowed in those browsers for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so thanks to you guys, I had an idea of what to look for and I stumbled upon [this](http://www.donatofurlani.it/category/programming/34/js_DOM_Flash_InternetExplorer) article.

The problem I have seems to be that for some ?security? reasons the flash would not load after being moved. I devised this dirty workaround, simply I force browser to parse and `recalculate` the `object` tag. Is it so? I hope I understand well what am I doing.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
     var copy = document.getElementById("s");
     document.getElementById("newparent").appendChild(copy);
     copy.innerHTML = copy.innerHTML; //dirty workaround
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="newparent"> <!-- here will the object be appended -->
  </div>
  <div id="s">
    <object width="50%" height="50%" data="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf">SWF Not shown</object>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```